# Exemples d'acronymes d'origine étrangère comme « yolo »

Tags: vocabulaire, acronymes

J'ai découvert que [yolo](https://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/dictionnaire/definition/yolo) était de plus en plus utilisé en français.

Est-ce que vous connaissez d'autres acronymes de ce type, d'origine étrangère, utilisés en français ?

Merci !

Comment: Lol, rotfl, wtf

Comment: rtfm, tl-dr (IT lingo)

Answer (score 2):

Il y en a beaucoup notamment d'origine anglaise comme:

*SMS* (Short Message Service), on utilise *texto* mais SMS est aussi utilisé., *VIP* (Very Important Person): C'est un VIP, *FAQ* (Frequently Asked Questions): Consultez la FAQ, *LOL* (Laughing Out Loud), *XOXO* à la fin d'un message, *RIP* (Rest In Peace), *ATM* (Automatic Teller Machine), ajoutez à cela la plupart des mots techniques utilisés en informatique (HTML, CSS, DOS, HTTP, FTP, ....)

Comment: *RIP* est plus largement connu comme l’abréviation du latin *[Requiescat in pace](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Requiescat_in_pace)* que *Rest in peace*.

Comment: Il y a d'autres abréviations notées qui ne sont pas des acronymes: SMS, ATM, HTTP. Un acronyme est une abréviation composées d'initiales ou de syllabes initiales qui se prononce comme un mot "normal" et non épelé lettre par lettre (ex: xoxo, faq, radar, sida, Benelux)

Comment: OK également je crois